# Didn't able to locate send files button

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, iframe

I am trying to locate a button that uploads a file and gets the ouput result by clicking the button on the page itself, I know how to upload file by send keys.

The website is https://huggingface.co/spaces/vaibhavsharda/semantic_clustering

My code is

```
import csv
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_autoinstaller
import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()  # Check if the current version of chromedriver exists
# and if it doesn't exist, download it automatically,
# then add chromedriver to path

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
count = 0
entire_data = []

driver.get("https://huggingface.co/spaces/vaibhavsharda/semantic_clustering")
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(10)
s = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.exg6vvm15 .edgvbvh9')   # the error is here.
s.send_keys("small_test.txt")
```

[image]

I am trying to locate element by selenium, I don't know if it doesn't load or something else is the error but I just want to locate the "Browse Files" button. Feel free to ask me anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Element you trying to click is inside an iframe, so you need first to switch into the iframe in order to access that element.
The following code works:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

url = "https://huggingface.co/spaces/vaibhavsharda/semantic_clustering"
driver.get(url)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[title]")))

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@kind='primary'][not(@disabled)]"))).click()
```

When finished don't forget to switch to the default content with:

```py
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

**UPD**
Uploading file with Selenium is done by sending the uploaded file to a special element. This is not an element you are clicking as a user via GUI to upload elements. The element actually receiving uploaded files normally matching this XPath: `//input[@type='file']`
This is the fully working code - I tried this on my PC uploading some text file.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

url = "https://huggingface.co/spaces/vaibhavsharda/semantic_clustering"
driver.get(url)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[title]")))

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='file']"))).send_keys("C:/project_name/.gitignore")
```

[image]

Comment: Prophet, the code is working fine but I want to upload files in it. How can I upload a txt file?

Comment: You wrote `I know how to upload file by send keys` ;)
I'll update the answer